# How do i put 3 windows side by side using keyboard shortcuts in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

Work gave me a new monitor - which is a 21:9 screen, so I would like to be able to put 3 windows side by side, but `ctrl` + `alt` + `keypad` shortcuts can only be used to place 2, and with this monitor those windows are almost too wide.

Comment: I've drafted a small script that asks for selecting 3 windows out of a list of all open windows, and will arrange them side by side. This script is still in development , very rough, but I'd like to know what you think of this so far. Script source is [here](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/799ca32ce34ebf9cbae659ac8570ad9c)  Keep in mind, you need to have `xdotool` installed in order for this to work

Comment: @serg That kinda works, but what I really want is just a shortcut to take up 1/3 of the screen, and I will need to move windows too often to type commands.

Comment: Seems like I overthought this :) So   Ctrl + Super + Right moves currently focused window right , we know that . What you want  is something like Ctrl + Super + 1  to position window 1/3 left , ctrl + Super + 2 to position 1/3 in the middle, and Ctrl + super + 3 to position 1/3 to the right. Is that correct ?

Comment: How's this ? https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/b4ca47e820614ea4f6b3e1a4295fa152 This can be made into a 3 different shortcuts

Comment: Is there some where to set a shortcut in bash? Anyway you should post that link as a reply and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Ubuntu's System Settings has section for setting custom shortcuts. I will post that in a minute and explain in detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Intro

The script below serves to resize windows to 1/3 of the screen width, and place them to either left, center, or right position.There are numeric options, 0 for left, 1 for center, and 2 for right.

The script relies on `xdotool` so make sure to install that with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`.

In Unity, the script must operate on **unmaximized** windows. The reason for that is because Unity locks windows in place when they are maximized, making them not respond to whatever command `xdotool` issues.

**Note:** This script will be updated and refined over time. I will likely add it to my personal github repository but as of right now it exists as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/b4ca47e820614ea4f6b3e1a4295fa152)

#### Setting Shortcut

Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd>  -> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> -> <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> -> <kbd>Custom</kbd> and click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the lower left corner to create new entry. Provide a custom name and full path to script ( or `bash /path/to/script ARG` ) as in my example .

[image]

Save it, and click on the right field . You will be prompted to press keys that you want to correspond to this shortcut. I've set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>.

[image]

You now have a shortcut for placing window to the left. Repeat the same steps for center and right shortcut.

#### Script Source

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# run script like so:  bash thirds.sh NUMBER
# where NUMBER is 0,1 or 2
# 0 is left, 1 is center, 2 is right
get_screen_geometry()
{
   # determine size of the desktop
   xwininfo -root | \
   awk  -F ':' '/Width/{printf "%d",$2/3}/Height/{print $2}' 
}
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize $(get_screen_geometry )

xdotool getactivewindow windowmove \
$(get_screen_geometry | awk -v POS=$1  '{ printf "%d ", POS*$1  }'  ) 0
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you <3

Comment: I was looking for that solution for two years. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work for me until I replaced the command with `sh -c "sh ~/thirds.sh 0"`

Answer (score 1):

The script below is *modified* version of answer by [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://askubuntu.com/a/790142/1231372) to resize windows to 1/3 of the screen width, and place them to either left, middle or right position **with single shortcut and works on maximized windows as well**.

The script relies on `xdotool` so make sure to install that with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`.

Add Keyboard Shortcut to the command `bash thirds.sh` (with no arguements).

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/nitincodery/e63b89978ed40889a3f6a35d94452c9a) of it too.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# assign keyboard shortcut to bash thirds.sh
# run shortcut on the window to resize
# it auto cycles to the position (0)left, (1)middle, (2)right

# create a counter file to store positions
counter="thirds-counter.txt"
if [[ -f $counter ]]; then
  count=$(<$counter)
else
  echo "0" > $counter
fi

# determine size of the desktop
get_screen_geometry()
{
   xwininfo -root | awk  -F ':' '/Width/{printf "%d",$2/3}/Height/{print $2}'
}

# unmaximize the window
xdotool key 'Ctrl+Super+Down'
sleep 1

# set size of the window to one third of total to the position 0,1,2
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize $(get_screen_geometry)
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove $(get_screen_geometry | awk -v POS=$count '{printf "%d", POS*$count}') 0

# store next position to the file
count=$(((($count+1))%3))
echo "$count" > $counter
```